# I am having an issue with pylint within visual studio code workspace settings

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, pylint

Every single one of the immport statements I make within the project files are giving an error:

`[Python] unresolved import 'user.models'`

with this statement:

`from users.models import Detail`

Here is my workspace settings.json file within my .vscode folder:

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "/Applications/Python3/bin/python3",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint",
  "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"],
  "python.venvPath": "${workspaceFolder}/backend/env/bin/python3",
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pep8Args": [
    "--ignore-E501"
],
"git.ignoreLimitWarning": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pyling_django` should be `pylint_django`, and you need to make sure your python path is correct, and your [ENV is activated](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Comment: I use conda for my virtual environment. Show the env path be absolute path from my computer... should i do the same thing for my python path. should it be absolut...

Comment: I am going to update my file content based on the changes that you suggested. I am still getting the same error message....